# What are post-workout l-glutamine supplementation benefits?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, nutrition, l-glutamine

This question excludes all possible benefits for the workout itself or exercise performance. It concerns post workout general well-being.

What does glutamine help with when it comes to post-workout artifacts such as recovery, fatigue, DOMS, and health in general? What about appetite suppression?

This question is assuming I do not take a post-workout protein shake and rely solely on glutamine.

Comment: Just so that you know, three basic facts: 1) glutamine is a standard building block of life and in basically all food. You don't take it, you eat it and you eat it any time you eat anything (if you are not into splitting hairs). 2) magic doesn't exist by definition. 3) people will buy anything if you tell them it's good for them. Believe me, I work for people that sell. Please reexamine if you really need to ask that question. Perhaps describe your problem instead that you want to cure with food magic and maybe someone will tell you a good solution. Perhaps its glutamine, who knows.

Answer (score 0):

[This paywalled article](https://bjsm.bmj.com/content/44/Suppl_1/i43.2) does suggest that glutamine dosage does reduce DOMS to a degree and that mobility returned after 36 hours (though the abstract didn't really report the return of mobility for the placebo group).

Glutamine is a nonessential amino acid, meaning that our body produces it, which makes sense because it is used for a lot of functions aside from building muscle. (Like it's a nitrogen donor for anabolic processes, carbon donor for keeping the citric acid cycle going, regulates pH in our kidneys, and transports ammonia through our body, among others)

While replenishing some glutamine may help in the post-workout, you might as well just do a regular protein shake instead of just focusing on glutamine. It seems silly to take a nonessential amino acid when our body makes it and it'd be better to take something that replenishes essential amino acids since our bodies don't make those.